# I want to install ubuntu in an ipad1 16 Gb, and I'm ready to follow your instructions

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, tablet

Wifi, read pdf, print through wifi, openoffice. there are about 15 million tablets ipad1 sold, waiting for it.

Answer (score 2):

As of now it is not possible and will not be possible in near future (you can take that as NEVER)

The bootloader to these devices are locked and they will only boot iOS. There is no way you can install any other OS.  There are project like [idroid] (http://www.idroidproject.org) for for porting andriod to older idevices (for which a bootloader exploit was found) ,   but to my knowledge no one is working with ubuntu on iDevice